# jQuery Rain "Animated Menu Icon" onclick not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I use [JQuery Rain](https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/AnimatedMenuIcon/) to create a animate menu but i can not add onclick inside menu items.
That is a beautiful effect for menu button and sub menu item,

I want to add onclick="alert(1);" on one of sub menu but apperantly the parent node prevent clicking on sub menu.

I try to change some css to access sub menu but i saw not any change.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Animated Menu Icon</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/AnimatedMenuIcon/css/normalize.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/AnimatedMenuIcon/css/demo.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/AnimatedMenuIcon/css/component.css" />
    <!--[if IE]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/AnimatedMenuIcon/js/segment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/AnimatedMenuIcon/js/ease.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content">
                <div class="device__screen">
                    <div id="menu-icon-wrapper" class="menu-icon-wrapper" style="visibility: hidden">
                        <svg width="1000px" height="1000px">
                        <path id="pathA" d="M 300 400 L 700 400 C 900 400 900 750 600 850 A 400 400 0 0 1 200 200 L 800 800"></path>
                        <path id="pathB" d="M 300 500 L 700 500"></path>
                        <path id="pathC" d="M 700 600 L 300 600 C 100 600 100 200 400 150 A 400 380 0 1 1 200 800 L 800 200"></path>
                        </svg>
                        <button id="menu-icon-trigger" class="menu-icon-trigger"></button>
                    </div><!-- menu-icon-wrapper -->

                </div><!-- /device-content -->
        </div><!-- /content -->
    </div><!-- /container -->
    <div id="dummy" class="dummy">
        <div class="dummy__item" onclick="alert(1);">Click me</div>
        <div class="dummy__item"></div>
        <div class="dummy__item"></div>
        <div class="dummy__item"></div>
    </div><!-- /dummy -->
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but if you want to see your sub menu delete:

```css
-webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0) translate3d(-2em, 0, 0) scale3d(0.5, 1, 1);
transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0) translate3d(-2em, 0, 0) scale3d(0.5, 1, 1);
```

in https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/AnimatedMenuIcon/css/demo.css
and it appear

[image]